# Can Spark accumulators be accessed via YARN?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to view the value of a Spark accumulator via YARN or the Spark Application UI, in the same way that map reduce counters can be viewed?

I have seen claims that you can at least view them from the application UI but I'm unable to find where.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to write a script to scrape these values.

Comment: The value of an accumulator is not a single value in the process, each task has its own accumulator which are 'accumulated' after the tasks finish. Therefore watching them in action won't mean much probably.

Comment: Is it possible to access historical data that has been aggregated once a job has finished running? This is what I would like to do; plot a graph of 'counter' values for periodic runs of the same job. I already have a script to do it for map reduce jobs which I would like to expand

Comment: Oh, if you mean resulting value in an accumulator after a *job* finishes, then there are a lot of ways to do that including printing it out accumulators to a file or stdin, serializing them into json and serving them on `HTTP`, emitting them as UDP packets. However, AFAIK, there is no way to see the values with the built-in Web UI or REST Framework.